# Scroll view with Layoutweight tag

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I want to implement scroll view  but with layoutweight attribute. Actually i want to display
my activity content on the full screen and if user scroll down then he can see Ads
how I can do this please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The you should add you ads banner INSIDE your scrollview... Something like that :

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.ads.adsbanner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myAdBaner"/>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And just add your content to "content".

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question completely but I think the following layout will work for you... Do tell if you have any prob

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- ADS -->
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: actualy its like i want to display my content on full screen but i have an ads which I want to dispaly at the bottom or user scoll down and he see the ad.when activity start ad is not visible on the screen but when user scroll down it shows ad

Comment: Then have a look at Cehm's answer.. I hope it will work for you :)